# Excel VBA - Allow Hyphen and single space in input

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this function to allow only A-Z characters in a user input, however I need to modify this to allow only single spaces and/or the hyphen symbol "-" as well.

Could this be done without regex, as I understand you need to have additional references to use regex in VBA?

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[a-zA-Z]", Len(strValue))
End Function
```

Comment: You mean - and single space should also be valid, right?

Comment: You could loop through characters maybe? And check for each CHAR() through an Case .... Then? Also, I believe regex should still be possible through late binding.

Comment: When you say single space are you talking one space total in the string or no spaces back to back?

Comment: I am looking for only 1 space between words and no trailing or ending spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the `-` and a space to the like:

```
"[-a-zA-Z ]"
```

---

If you want to not allow double spaces(two spaces back to back) or trailing or preceding spaces use this:

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[-a-zA-Z ]", Len(strValue)) And _
       Len(strValue) = Len(Application.Trim(strValue))
End Function
```

[image]

If instead you only want to allow 1 space in the entire string then use this:

```
Public Function IsAlpha(strValue As String) As Boolean
    IsAlpha = strValue Like WorksheetFunction.Rept("[-a-zA-Z ]", Len(strValue)) And _
        Len(strValue) <= Len(Replace(strValue, " ", "")) + 1
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: This would allow for more than single spaces

Comment: @AAA now it does not.